# Optimize SQL query in foreach() loop

Tags: php, mysql

How else can I get the `name` without putting the query in the foreach loop?

PHP:

```
$material_decode=json_decode($materials['materials']);
foreach($material_decode as $material_id=>$material_value)
{
    $forge_materials=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT `name` FROM `forging_materials` WHERE `id`='.$material_id.' LIMIT 1'));
    echo '<tr>'.
        '<td>'.
            $forge_materials['name'].
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.
            number_format($material_value).
        '</td>'.
    '</tr>';
}
```

$material_decode (forge_material_id => material_value):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [2] => 25
    [4] => 32
    [5] => 23
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch all needed records at once using **WHERE IN** outside the loop. **Only single query will be neccessary** this way.

This will work for you:

```
$material_decode = json_decode($materials['materials'], true);
$forge_materials = mysql_query('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `forging_materials` WHERE `id` IN ( '. implode(',', array_keys($material_decode)) .')');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($forge_materials))
{
    echo '<tr>'.
      '<td>'.
        $row['name'].
      '</td>'.
      '<td>'.
        number_format($material_decode[$row['id']]).
      '</td>'.
    '</tr>';
}
```

Keep in mind that **mysql_** methods have been deprecated and it is now advised to use **PDO** or **mysqli_** methods instead. You can read more in the docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Dear down-voters - please leave a comment, I'd love to learn what's wrong with that code :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think about using `IN()`. I'm aware mysql_ is depreciated and the site is in the process of getting recoded to use MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

First run `SELECT id,name FROM forging_materials WHERE 1` it will fetch all id & names from the table and then in the foreach loop, get the name from the query result which have id equals to `$material_id`

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code. Try this

```
$forge_materials_name   =   "";

$material_decode=json_decode($materials['materials']);
foreach($material_decode as $material_id=>$material_value)
{
    if( empty($forge_materials_name) )
    {
        $forge_materials=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT `name` FROM `forging_materials` WHERE `id`='.$material_id.' LIMIT 1'));  
        $forge_materials_name   =   $forge_materials['name'];
    }
    echo '<tr>'.
        '<td>'.
            $forge_materials_name.
        '</td>'.
        '<td>'.
            number_format($material_value).
        '</td>'.
    '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? $forge_materials_name will be fetched only for the first material and then used in every loop run. Every row displayed should show the name corresponding to the id.